# I'm having an error with Ramotion tab bar configuration

Tags: swift

I'm following from [this](https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar) site how to set up and use this animation tab bar.

I did all the following instructions but there still is error:

> Concept[4854:174780] Unknown class RAMAnimatedTabBarController in Interface Builder file.

Can somebody help me please, I'm very upset about this problem. Hope for positive response.

Comment: Have you narrowed the problem down to the exact code snippet that is throwing the error? When you do that it would be helpful if you post it here so we can help you debug the problem further.